# How to modify a column in SQL table from short text to long text

Tags: mysql, sql

How to modify a column in SQL table from short text to long text. while running this query ALTER TABLE Taxes MODIFY Description LONGTEXT;" am getting inorrect sytax near 'MODIFY'. Here Taxes is the table name and Description is the column name. I don't have owner rights to the table to execute query directly in the SQL aplication. i can execute the query through application which is connected to SQL server.

Comment: On which database program?

Comment: in mysql this runs with out a problem, can you give more information about your system Version

Answer (score 0):

to fix the modify syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE `Taxes ` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Description` `Description` LONGTEXT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MariaDB 10.3.25 your statement works without issues:

```sql
MariaDB [stackoverflow]> CREATE TABLE Taxes ( Description TEXT );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.846 sec)

MariaDB [stackoverflow]> ALTER TABLE Taxes MODIFY Description LONGTEXT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (4.395 sec)              
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I wonder if there is something more going on here.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE [Table_Name] ALTER COLUMN [Column_Name] NTEXT

Finally this worked. I figured out shortly. and i forgot to post i here.

Thanks Everyone.